# Widgets in the WordPress dashboard are not loading for long after updating the WordPress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, widget

[Screenshot images click to open.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HOLU.png)

Today, I updated my WordPress website, and when I go to my Widget area, it keeps loading for a long time and throws an error. Screenshot attached. Sometimes there are many red lines showing. Also, the designs of widgets changed.

I cleared the cache, but no luck.
I just want the old-style widgets that are super easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reckon I have found one solution.
I installed a plugin called WP Classic Widgets. It will generate the older-style widgets, with apparently no errors on the website.
I am not sure for how long this plugin will work, but for a temporary solution, it works well.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).